# Cpp forward class declaration and union

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, unions, forward-declaration

I get the following error from VS Code when I try to use Cpp forward class declaration within union definition.

```
variable "mate::Data" is not a type name
class std::vector<<error-type> *>
```

Is there something wrong or It's a VS Code bug ?

[Cpp forward class declaration and union - VS Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ2ke.png)

```
class Data;

enum DataType
{
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_NUMBER,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_NUMBER_POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_NUMBER_NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_STRING,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_OBJECT,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_ARRAY,
    DATA_UNIT_TYPE_NULL,
};

union DataUnion {
    bool boolValue;
    double numberValue;
    std::string* stringValue;
    std::vector<Data*>* arrayValue; // <- error here 
    std::map<std::string, Data*>* objectValue; // <- and there
};

class Data
{
private:
    DataType type;
    DataUnion value;
    bool hasNullValue;
public:
    ~Data();
    Data(DataType t);
    Data(DataType t, DataUnion v);
};
```

Comment: Is this really what your file looks like ? Seems like `DataUnion` is defined in different namespace (mate::).

Comment: Sorry @Filip-Kočica I updated my post with DataType definition. Class `Data`, union `DataUnion` and Enum `DataType` are in the same namespace `mate`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5e451e681ec9bc4

Comment: It seems like it's a bug from my VS Code

Comment: `std::` or `boost::` `variant` might be useful to replace your union.

Answer (score 0):

I [cannot reproduce your error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a88181d4827806b), but you never define `DataType`. Following Clang's output [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a88181d4827806b):

```
main.cpp:18:5: error: unknown type name 'DataType'
    DataType type;
    ^
main.cpp:23:10: error: unknown type name 'DataType'
    Data(DataType t);
         ^
main.cpp:24:10: error: unknown type name 'DataType'
    Data(DataType t, DataUnion v);
         ^
3 errors generated.
```

Provide a definition and you should be good to go. This seems to have nothing to do with the DataUnion thing you have.